# Is there a self-hosted single sign-on solution with completely RESTful API?

Tags: authentication, rest, authorization, single-sign-on, identity-management

Is there a single sign-on solution with completely RESTful API installable on my server? I have looked at OpenAM, which have some of the API available through HTTP/JSON, but not all (and seems too heavy, but if it had all the API, I'd not care).

Do you know of solution for authorization, authentication and identity management that can be used for single sign-on and has all (maybe without setting admin password and such critical issues) its API available though HTTP(S)/JSON?

I have no need for Java API etc., HTTP(S)+CLI for setup is only thing I look for. That is, I doin;t realkly care what the solution is implemented in (no need for Java EE etc.) as far as it does its job and it is secure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Mozilla's new [Persona](http://www.mozilla.org/persona/) solution built on [BrowserID](https://github.com/mozilla/browserid)? It does a lot, but it's hard to know if it's sufficient for you without more details about how integrated you need the authorization to be.

Comment: I will have a look. Suite of applications, run as parts of a bigger whole, built all from ground-up. So identity management centralized, in-house, but secure and mature enough to be usable enough for companies as well as villages/cities. I want to be able to separate all parts clearly, so I want to be able to use auth/IdP through (intranet) https.

Comment: Interesting piece of software, but it seems not to fit the need. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/). They're the largest identify management service (for developers) -- and they are all REST + JSON API backed.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to make clear I look for self-hosted solution, not cloud one.

Comment: Makes sense! Just a heads up though: you can purchase stormpath to run locally yourself. They have a licensing model for on-premise edition stuff (not sure if this is what you want).